# Remove top close 'X' button from from Prime vue dialog

Tags: vuejs3, primevue

How to remove the close (X) icon from PrimeVue `<Dialog> </Dialog>`

[image]

Comment: Hi, what did you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
:closable="false"
```

as bellow inside `Dialog` tag

```
<Dialog :closable="false">
```